# Nested rules in firebase

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nested

I want to create a nested collection into a firebase object, but I'm still new in this technologies. How can I create a schema like that in firebase Realtime database?

```
"consultants": {
  "id_1": {
    "name": "foo",
    "items": [
      {
         "field1": "value1",
         "text1" : "text1"
      },
      {
          "field1": "value2",
          "text1" : "text2"
      }
    ]

  }

}
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you're asking. Can you edit your question to include something that you've tried already? Maybe that will clarify it enough for someone to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are new, I would like to suggest you to learn about [JSON](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp) as firebase database is structured in the JSON way.

Once you got some clue, you can proceed to [here (Realtime Database Data Structure)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data) and [here (Firestore Database Data Structure)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model), to start structuring your database.

Hope it helps!